# Creating a quick entry feature in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a pretty good project task management system going in Microsoft Access, but one feature I'm still missing is some type of 'quick entry' like facility often found in many good productivity applications.

This is how it would work:

Scenario 1:

You're in another application, working on a few things, and you just remember something that needs to get done. You hit your predefined shortcut: CTRL + ALT + T (again, from outside Microsoft Access) and it brings up a small access form with a text box in to which you can type what needs to get done, e.g.

Inform key stakeholders of concerns regarding timeline

you hit return and that gets saved as a record in Microsoft Access instantly.

An alternative, and slightly more complex scenario...

Scenario 2:

As above, but you want to add further details besides the task name, such as the person you need to speak to, and a due date. The input in to the text box could look like this:

Inform @Sally of concerns regarding timeline >+3

Where '@' tells access to populate a field called 'Contact' with 'Sally' (unless it already exists) and '>+3' is interpreted by access to mean a due date 3 days from today.

How difficult are Scenario 1 and Scenario 2 to perform? What level of VBA/programming knowledge would be required?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say it requires a fair amount of confidence in VBA.

You need to register a global hot-key; that is, a keyboard-combination that can be captured from outside the Access application. It requires win-api calls. Here is [some code](http://vba-programmer.com/Snippets/Code_VB/Creating_a_Global_Hotkey.html).

You need to know where to place these calls. I believe you have to put them in a standard module, not in the form's class module. (I haven't double-checked this, it's late.)

You need to have a little understanding about what this code is doing. NEVER attempt to type this api-code - copy it from a reliable source, exactly as it is!! You don't need to fully understand the code, but you need to know how (and when) to call each function.

Once you've registered the hot-key then your VBA needs to bring your application to the front and display your form, and focus it. Reliably bringing the application to the front may also require api-calls.

Once your form is opened (and focused) you can have a button on it to parse the information in its textbox. However, if you are designing the form anyway, I would add checkboxes, comboboxes, etc., rather than trying to parse a complex sentence/ statement.

Comment: Mm what's wrong with using Alt-Tab to activate your application, and then perhaps just have a hot-key within your application to show the form..? It is important to consider the simpler options :)

Comment: Thanks for your insight. I suggested the text based entry because, I've found it is actually quicker than using the mouse/keyboard to select various check boxes etc

Your suggestion to use Alt-Tab is completely sensible, I have found myself extremely reliant on having the global hot key available wherever I work (I am a management consultant and often have multiple excel documents open so it can be tedious to alt-tab to the application).

Looking at what you've provided it seems to be slightly out of my very basic skill set however so I may need to just live with the minor inconvenience :)

Comment: You might investigate the applications that are already available to assign global hotkeys in Windows. I'm not sure if, or how, this would help you with your already running Access instance. FYI you may already be aware but pressing Ctrl-Tab within Excel moves between workbooks.